# Select element matching ID after a certain element, or create it if it doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div id="foo">
  FOO
</div>

<div id="nextfoo"></div>
```

How can I select #nextfoo from a `$('#foo').each()...` function, and if it doesn't exist then create it ?

Comment: An element id on a page has to be unique, should you shouldn't have more than one element with `id="foo"`. you should probably use `class="foo"` and `$('.foo').each()` instead

Comment: You want to look for nextfoo within foo ? And if it doesn't exist where do you want to put nextfoo within foo or after foo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nextFoo= $('#nextfoo');
if (!nextFoo.length){
    nextFoo=$('<div id="nextfoo"/>').insertAfter('#foo');
}
```

you mean something like this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all ids should be unique on a given page. So there is no need to have `each` loop on $("#foo")

You can use jQuery `next` method to get the next element(#nextfoo). If it is not present then you can insert it using jQuery `after` method. Try this

```
if(!$("#foo").next().is('#nextfoo')){
    $("#foo").after('div id="nextfoo" />');
}
else{//It exists
    var nextfoo = $("#foo").next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, every id should be unique. So if is this structure which you are looking to have repeated...

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="nextfoo"></div>
```

... and you are missing some 'nextfoo' classes after your 'foos' then you can do something like the following:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).next().hasClass('nextfoo')) {
        $(this).after('<div id="nextfoo">nextfoo 2</div>');
    }
});
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jL9J6/) of this in action.